# Calculated transient value is null after deserialisation with Gson

Tags: kotlin, gson

I run into an error which I do not understand after deserializing with gson.
My usecase is way more complex, but I created this test below which shows the behaviour I see.
The issue is the calculated transient value (allObjs) that is null after deserialisation. The unit test fails on the last assert.
Apparently the @Transient prevents correct initialisation of allObjs after deserialisation.

Is this expected behaviour? Can I do anything to make the field work in this way?

If not then I have to convert all the transient fields to functions like getThemAll(), which does work.

I hope for any insights.

Regards, Rob

```
class CoupleDeserializeTest {

    data class Couple( val objA: String, val objB: String){
        @Transient
        val allObjs: List<String> = listOf(objA, objB)

        fun getThemAll() = listOf(objA, objB)
    }

    @Test
    fun testDe_SerializeCouple() {

        val couple = Couple("my", "text")

        // This succeeds
        Assert.assertNotNull(couple.allObjs)

        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(couple)

        // This succeeds
        Assert.assertEquals("{\"objA\":\"my\",\"objB\":\"text\"}", json)

        val coupleDeserialized = gson.fromJson<Couple>(json, Couple::class.java)

        // This succeeds
        Assert.assertNotNull(coupleDeserialized.getThemAll())

        // This fails
        Assert.assertNotNull(coupleDeserialized.allObjs)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are marking a field as `Transient`, it will ignore the field from serialisation or deserialisation, snippet from `JvmFlagAnnotations`

```
/**
 * Marks the JVM backing field of the annotated property as `transient`, meaning that it is not
 * part of the default serialized form of the object.
 */
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@MustBeDocumented
public actual annotation class Transient
```

**EDIT**

It will ignore it in initialisation because, the value of `objA` and `objB` will be initialised using serialisation meaning `objA` and `objB` have not assigned by the time you `allObjs` gets initialised, to get the values later instead of directly assigning, you can use `get()`

```
data class Couple( val objA: String, val objB: String){
     @Transient
     val allObjs: List<String>
           get() = listOf(objA, objB)

     fun getThemAll() = listOf(objA, objB)
}
```

Comment: But apparently it also ignores it with initialisation: it is a calculated field

Comment: Updated the answer, this way it won't be null

Comment: I tried that, but still null, maybe cause in my real class allObjs is an inhererited field from an interface